# ag (the_silver_searcher) not searching entire file - does it have an implicit maximum input size?

Tags: macos, unix, grep

I have a very large plain text file (multiple gigabytes in size) which I need to search for certain strings. When using `grep`, I get over 11,000 matches of a string but with `ag` I get roughly 1,500. The output of the two commands is the same up to the point where `ag` stops.

I am aware of the `-m` option in `ag` defining the maximum number of matches but this defaults to 10,000 and so is not the issue.

To illustrate this, here is an example of what's happening:

```
$ grep -i 'string' hugefile.txt | wc -l
    11000
$ ag -i 'string' hugefile.txt | wc -l
    1500
```

The output of the two commands is identical to the same number of matches:

```
$ grep -m 1500 -i 'string' hugefile.txt > grep_output.txt
$ ag --no-numbers -i 'string' hugefile.txt > ag_output.txt

$ diff grep_output.txt ag_output.txt

(files identical)
```

Does `ag` have an implicit maximum input size and if so, is it possible to alter this?

Comment: Same here. Except my file has only 1.5 GB. With Grep it is slower, but complete :/

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you had multiple (in average 6 to 7) hits per line?

If so, the above method to count them is wrong: It only counts lines with matches, but not matches. So if you reach the limit of 10000 matches already after 1500 lines with matches, you'll get the above result and it would be *correct*.

Additionally the semantics of `grep`'s and `ag`'s `-m` option seem to differ:

- For `grep` it's the maximum count of lines being read: *Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.*
- But for `ag` it's the maximum count of matches: *Skip the rest of a file after NUM matches.*

So I suspect you've hit the default maximum limit of matches and need to increase the value passed to the `-m` option of `ag`.